# How to repeatedly poll a server-side controller for an action in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, custom-controller, javascript-controller

There's a Lightning Component with a button. Its `onClick` attribute points to a client-side controller's function. It invokes helper's function which I would like to start a polling routine to a server-side controller.

Client's code:

```
initiatePolling : function(cmp, callEvent) {
        var myFunction = function() {
            console.log('Inside myFunction');
            var action = cmp.get("c.myServerSideFunction");
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                console.log("Inside myServerSideFunction callback");
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                    console.log("Success: " + response.getReturnValue());
                } else {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
            setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
        }
        myFunction();
}
```

Server's code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String myServerSideFunction() {
    return 'Server-side callback';
}
```

The problem is that after clicking the button, in a console I receive the following messages:

```
Inside myFunction
Inside myServerSideFunction callback
Success: Server-side callback
Inside myFunction
Inside myFunction
Inside myFunction
etc...
```

It looks like the server-side callback is received only once. Why does it happen? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've finally figured it out. It looks like it's possible to repeatedly poll the server-side controller.

For the first, I put `setTimeout` inside of the action's callback, at the bottom of function's body, to make it sure that the next invocation will happen after receiving server's response. But it wasn't enough since after a second invocation of `myFunction` the code stopped its execution. It turned out that there's a little section about a `getCallback` function at the bottom of the [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) article:

> If your action is not executing, make sure that you’re not executing
>   code outside the framework’s normal rerendering lifecycle. For
>   example, if you use `window.setTimeout()` in an event handler to execute
>   some logic after a time delay, wrap your code in `$A.getCallback()`. You
>   don't need to use `$A.getCallback()` if your code is executed as part of
>   the framework's call stack; for example, your code is handling an
>   event or in the callback for a server-side controller action.

Another helpful article is [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm).

I wrapped `setTimeout` function in a `getCallback` and it finally started working:

```
Inside myFunction
Inside myServerSideFunction callback
Success: Server-side callback
Inside myFunction
Inside myServerSideFunction callback
Success: Server-side callback
Inside myFunction
Inside myServerSideFunction callback
Success: Server-side callback
...
```

Here's the proper code:

```
initiatePolling : function(cmp, callEvent) {
        var myFunction = function() {
            console.log('Inside myFunction');
            var action = cmp.get("c.myServerSideFunction");
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                console.log("Inside myServerSideFunction callback");
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                    console.log("Success: " + response.getReturnValue());
                } else {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
                setTimeout($A.getCallback(myFunction), 1000);
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
        myFunction();
}
```

Comment: thank you so, so, so, so, so, much for this.

Answer (score 4):

Since the actions are asynchronous, they will not execute in the order you expect. Your code works, you just need to you leave your console open long enough and you will see batches of server side actions executed simoultaneously after some time. This is specified in the lightning components developer guide  section under [Calling a Server-Side Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

> $A.enqueueAction(action) adds the server-side controller action to the queue of actions to be executed. All actions that are enqueued will run at the end of the event loop. Rather than sending a separate request for each individual action, the framework processes the event chain and batches the actions in the queue into one request. The actions are asynchronous and have callbacks.

This post answered by @martin --> [Use of setCallBack() in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132629/use-of-setcallback-in-lightning) can provide furhter details on using callback functions in lightning controllers and interacting with servers side actions

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I understand correctly that there isn't any way of synchronous polling in Salesforce? I tried putting the ``setTimeout`` inside of the ``setCallback`` body but after that the function invokes only twice (where the second time gives only ``"Inside myFunction"``).

Comment: correct, you cant synchronously call server side actions and expect the server to responf when you want due to the Architecture.

Comment: But shouldn't it work after putting ``setTimeout`` inside of the callback's body? Thanks to that, in my opinion, next call should be invoked only after receiving a data from the server. Sadly the routine just stops its execution.

Comment: this post--> [Use of setCallBack() in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132629/use-of-setcallback-in-lightning) might be of interest to you